# How do I display a single object with TemplateView?

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views

I am working on creating an "About" app for my website that dynamically generates "About" pages. For the index page of the app, I specifically want it to display the "About Us" page with a subsequent list of pages in the app.

What I am struggling to figure out is how do I access that single object from my queryset and display it through a TemplateView?

Here is the current code for the view:

```
class AboutIndexView(TemplateView):

    template_name = 'about/about.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(AboutIndexView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['about_page'] = Page.objects.all().exclude(title='About Us')
        context['about_us'] = Page.objects.filter(title='About Us')
        return context
```

Here is the current code for the template:

```
{% for page in about_us %}
    <div class="text-center">
        <h3>{{ page.title }}</h3>
    </div>
    {{ page.body|safe|linebreaks }}
{% endfor %}
```

Just to reiterate the question, how would I change my view code so that I no longer have to create a for loop in my template code, but just be able to display the "About Us" directly?

Comment: `filter` gives a queryset (In your case a list of a single item), use `Page.objects.get(title='About Us')` OR use `Page.objects.filter(title='About Us').first()`.

Comment: If you want to display an object, you should use the relevant class based view: DetailView.